# Не срабатывает after

Tags: css

Здравствуйте! Пытаюсь, используя псевдоэлемент :after, дописать что-нибудь после всех картинок определенного класса. Но ничего не выводится.

```
.model_images_preview {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #000;
}
img.model_images_preview::after {
    content: 'что-нибудь';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Note. This specification does not fully define the interaction of :before and :after with replaced elements (such as IMG in HTML). This will be defined in more detail in a future specification.

Из [официальной спецификации](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#before-after-content). В общем, пока с `<img>` работать не будет.

Comment: Спасибо, но так тоже не работает

Comment: Переписал ответ.