# ::after не срабатывает(в Chrome срабатывает)

Tags: html, css

Не отображается псевдоэлемент:

```css
.imagicks{
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   top: 28px;
   right: 98px;
}
.imagicks::after{
   content:"hello";
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
   <img class="imagicks" 
    src="https://acom.ru/images/2.0/kolvo_prosmotrov.png" 
    alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: `after` - это элемент **внутри** элемента. `img` - не может содержать в себе другие элементы, поэтому `after` и не добавляется

Comment: Надо ставить одно двоеточие, а не два. `.imagicks:after { ... }`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не срабатывает after](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/200012/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-after)

Comment: @Cricket, ты не прав.

Comment: @Cricket https://webref.ru/css/after

Comment: @Grundy а почему в такой же ситуации срабатывает `::before`?

Comment: @Proshka, Докажи, что `::before` срабатывает **в такой же** ситуации

Comment: Кстати забавно, но в хроме приведенный сниппет работает

Comment: @Grundy, http://htmlbook.ru/css/after ну по этому когда-то ориентировался.

Comment: @Cricket устарело

Comment: @Proshka, по твоей ссылке нет ничего про применение after/before к `img`

Comment: @Grundy ссылка была для Cricket

Comment: а, точно. @Cricket, в последних спецификациях ввели разделение на псевдо-классы, которые пишутся с одним двоеточием, и псевдо-элементы, которые пишутся с двумя.

Comment: @Grundy, хмм, спасибо за информацию!) Давно не смотрел, как же быстро все меняется..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С `img` `:after`, `:before` не работают (кроме Хрома), оберни `img` дивом с классом `imagicks`, а для картинки измени не много селектор:

```
.imagicks img{
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   top: 28px;
   right: 98px;
}
```

Comment: Chrome впереди планеты всей: в нем они работают и с img

Comment: хороший вариант

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, большинство браузеров не поддерживают использование :before или :after на теги IMG.

http://lildude.co.uk/after-css-property-for-img-tag

Тем не менее, вы можете выполнить то, что вам нужно с JavaScript/jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/xixonia/ahnGT/

```js
$(function() {

  $('.target').after('hello');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="target" width="200" height="100">
```

Или же на чистом js

```js
window.onload = function(){
 
  document.querySelector(".target").insertAdjacentText('afterend', "hello");
}
```

```html
<img class="target" width="200" height="100">
```

Ну если вы так не хотите использовать js то как вариант

```css
span::after {
  content: 'hello';
}
```

```html
<span><img class="target" width="200" height="100"></span>
```

Comment: очень плохое решение менять outerhtml

Comment: а как еще это сделать?

Comment: например: [Element.insertAdjacentElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement)

Comment: тогда уж `insertAdjacentText`

Comment: В зависимости от того, что именно надо вставлять, там еще и Html есть

Comment: Ну да это уже смотря на потребности

Comment: @Duoxx - в любом случае, спасибо за варианты, но нужен был чистый html+css